# How to prevent user navigate back to a JSP page after logout from the system?

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, cookies

Currently, I had invalidated session on the logout page and also clear the cache in the Main Menu. But it displays the HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error when I click the Back button.

How to keep displaying the login page since the session is invalidated instead of this error?

```
Mainmene.jsp
<%
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");
    response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store");
    response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
    response.setDateHeader ("Expires", 0);

    if(session.getAttribute("email")==null) {
        response.sendRedirect("loginpage.jsp"); // GO TO LOGIN PAGE
        }
    %>


Logout.java
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");

        HttpSession session=request.getSession();  
        session.invalidate(); 

        response.sendRedirect("loginpage.jsp");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Filter` that checks if there is a user object in the sessionScope and apply it to a given type of `url-patterns`. You can check [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/servlet-filter) to see how to use.